# Safari converts File to [object Object] when inserted into FormData. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, safari, uploading

I'm posting a file in Javascript using the new FormData interface. When I send a file using Safari 5.1.5 using "multipart/form-data", Safari coerces the File into a string, and instead of sending the actual file contents, it sends `[object Object]`.

Example:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", file);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "https://example.com/upload", true);
xhr.send(formdata);
```

What Safari ends up sending:

```
Origin: https://example.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.5 Safari/534.55.3
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycLc5AIMWzGxu58n8
Referer: https://example.com/upload

------WebKitFormBoundarycLc5AIMWzGxu58n8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

[object Object]
```

My file is therefore uploaded, but the contents of the file are, you guessed it, `[object Object]`.

What in the world is going on here? Is this a Safari bug?

#### Edit 1

For those curious how to dynamically generate a JS Blob, here's an example:

```
var Builder = (window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.BlobBuilder);
var builder = new Builder();
builder.append("hello, world");
var file = builder.getBlob("text/plain")
```

Unfortunately this does *not* work on Safari, so it didn't really help to include it in the question.

#### Edit 2

The file object I reference is from a drop action on a DOM element. Here's an example for how to retrieve a file. Run the following after the DOM has loaded.

```
function cancel(e) {
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

function drop(e) {
    cancel(e);
    for (var i=0; i<e.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
        file = e.dataTransfer.files[i];
    }
}

var elem = document.getElementById("upload-area");
elem.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
```

Comment: Need to see the code that defines your `file` variable on line 2.

Comment: `file` is provided by a drag and drop action. It's not dynamically created. In other browsers you can build a `Blob` dynamically, but Safari isn't able to do that yet.

Comment: Question updated with code explaining how I get the `file` object.

Comment: Just put pretty much this exact code up on a quick and dirty page on my server and it seems to work okay. It justs posts to a PHP file that places the upload into a temp directory, then reads its contents and echoes it back. kevincennis.com/uploadtest.

Comment: Whoa--so it does work. The plot thickens. This must have something to do with something I left out of the question (I didn't think it was relevant...I'm thinking it is now). I'm sending the file through postMessage to an iframe inside the page that receives the drop. The iframe contains the script that listens until the postMessage is received, creates the `FormData`, and then posts to the URL.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh. I bet postMessage is coercing the file object into a string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9520/discussion-between-dan-and-kennis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This didn't seem relevant when I was asking the question, but I figured this one out. Before uploading the file using XMLHttopRequest, I called jQuery's `$.ajax` method to call an endpoint in our backend to prep the file.

In short: this is a bug in jQuery on Safari. I was using a for loop to process a list of files, and upload them. I passed a file object as a parameter to the jQuery `$.ajax` method so that the file object I wanted wouldn't be rewritten as multiple loops were executed. E.g.

```
for (i in files) {
    var file = files[i];
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        myFile: file,
        success: function(response) {
            var file = this.myFile;
            // ...
    });
}
```

Turns out that jQuery happens to clone the `file` object incorrectly in Safari. So instead of casting it to a file when set to `this.myFile`, it casts it into an object, thus making it lose all of its special "file-like" capabilities. The other browsers appear to understand that the object is still a file despite this.

The answer is to write a callback method to handle the file uploads.

```
function handleFile(file) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            // ...
    });
}

for (var i in files) {
    handleFile(files[i]);
}
```

P.S. Going to file this to the jQuery bug tracker, but just wanted to keep this here in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`file` needs to be a `String`, otherwise if it's an `Object` its `toString()` method gets called when you append it to the form data object.

This is directly related to `Blob` not working in Safari. In order to get this working in Safari you would need a way to coerce the file into a `String` yourself, which obviously isn't the easiest thing to do (don't even know if it's possible for security reasons?).

Comment: Yeah, without full blob support it's not possible. However, in WebKit, Chrome, + Firefox you can call the file's slice method to retrieve specific bytes (useful for multipart uploads). Also, I just realized I left out a key part of the question--the file I'm uploading was received through postMessage in an iframe.

Comment: Also, I assumed the same as you did, but when you call `toString()` on the file object, it will get coerced to `[object File]`, not `[object Object]`.