# File converted to [Object object] string if sent using FormData in web app on iOS & Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I am building a web app based on Cordova/PhoneGap which uploads files to a server using a multipart/form-data POST request.

The following code works on BlackBerry 10:

```
var postRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (postRequest.overrideMimeType) {
    postRequest.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
}
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('param1', 'value1');
[...]
fd.append('file', file, fileName);
postRequest.open('POST', url, true);
postRequest.send(fd);
```

However on an iPhone running iOS6 the `File` object is replaced by the `String` [Object object] when sent to the server, similar to the issue described in [Safari converts File to [object Object] when inserted into FormData. How to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951531/safari-converts-file-to-object-object-when-inserted-into-formdata-how-to-fix).

In contrast to that issue I am not cloning the File object. My app is invoked with documents from other apps via the "Open in..." menu. I am passed a local file system URI which I resolve using `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI()`. This works perfectly and I receive first a FileEntry and from that a File object. However it appears this object is not recognized correctly and its `toString()` method is called instead when transmitting the request to the server.

Is this a bug on iOS? Or maybe a bug in PhoneGap when creating the File object? What is the best workaround?

**UPDATE**: I just ran into the same problem on Android, so this problem doesn't seem to be specific to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround for iOS seems to be to read the file using FileReader, construct a new Blob object from it and then transmit this to the server instead:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
     var fileBlob = new Blob([evt.target.result], { 'type' : fileType });
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

The Blob constructor used here requires iOS 6.0 or higher. This way the data was completely transmitted to the server as intended.

A Blob can be created on Android, too, using WebKitBlobBuilder. Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem on Android during my tests.

Comment: Same issue here. So it seems it's still better to use Phonegap's FileTransfer. That also answers my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480725/is-phonegaps-filetransfer-object-obsolete-with-xmlhttprequest2

Comment: Yes, especially on Android this seems to be the only solution that currently works.